# Discretization of this Coupled PDE System

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Below is a system of differential equations pertaining to the process of photobleaching a material using UV light. I've obtained this set of equations from a few different sources. I've been trying to verify the graphical solutions expressed within these sources, but I'm obtaining values that are way off.

I have this question set up into two sections. The first containing the given information that I've been trying to verify and the second section shows my attempts at solving the following PDEs.

I'm just curious as to where I might have gone wrong.

Thank you in advance.

$$ \underline{\textbf{Section 1}} $$
$$
\ \\
\text{System of Equations} \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = \frac{-\epsilon \cdot \phi}{N_A\cdot h \cdot v} \ \cdot \ C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \\
$$
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = -\epsilon \cdot C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \\
\ \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
\ \\
\text{Constants} \\
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
\epsilon = 97.7 \\
\phi = 0.2 \\
v = 1 \cdot 10^{15} \\
N_A = 6.022 \cdot 10^{23} \ (\text{Avagradro's Number})\\
h = 6.626\cdot 10^{-34}\ (\text{Planck's Constant})\\
$$
$$
\rule{9cm}{0.4pt} \\
\ \\
\ \\
\text{Initial & Boundary $$ Conditions} \\
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
$$
$$
C(x,0) = 0.0268 \\
I(0,t) = 10 \\
\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\Big|_{x=0} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\Big|_{x=x_{max}}= 0 \\ 
\ \\
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}
\ \\
$$
$$
\text{Final Graphical Solutions} \\
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
$$
[image]

[image]

Each Graph has its description below them. Figure 1 is the normalized initiator concentration represents $\frac{C}{C_0}$, while in Figure 2 the normalized intensity represents $\frac{I}{I_0}$

$$ \underline{\textbf{Section 2}} $$
As I've seen in many forums and textbooks, the first step for solving this system is with the finite difference method (FDM). My sources used a FDM to solve for each of the points in the graphs shown above, but they never specified how it was solved for.
I first discovered an additional $\textit{Initial Condition}$:
$$
K = \frac{\epsilon \cdot \phi}{N_A\cdot h \cdot v}\\
\ \\
C(0,t) = C_0*e^{-K\cdot I_0\cdot t}\\
$$

The part that I can't get right is the discretization of the equations. Does this logic work out below?
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = -K \ \cdot \ C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \ ; \ \frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = -\epsilon \cdot C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \\
$$
$$
\frac{1}{K}\cdot \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} =-C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \ ; \ \frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot \frac{\partial I}{\partial x} = -C(x,t)\cdot I(x,t) \\
$$
$$
\frac{1}{K}\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}\\
$$
When discretizing this combined PDE, I decided to use only the Forward Difference Method, because I could only verify the initial conditions.
$$
\frac{1}{K}\frac{C_{i,j+1}-C_{i,j}}{\Delta t} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\cdot \frac{I_{i+1,j}-I_{i,j}}{\Delta x}\\
$$
The "$i$" represented in this case is the spatial dimension of x-values (displacement), while the "$j$" is the spatial dimension of t-values (time).

I'm not asking anyone to solve this problem, but let me know if this is the correct approach. I've tried using Matlab, Python, and Mathematica functions to help me out, and to no avail.

Thank you again for attempting to help. Sorry for all the information. I thought it would be helpful.